# Getting the form to submit/ email

Tags: forms, jquery, send

I'm trying to figure this stuff out as I'm going so some expert help and advice would be appreciated. I have a form - using jQuery and Ajax, at the moment I dont know whats working - like if I submit it echos back the data input (only one field - still need to figure out how to add more to the code) but nothing comes through to my email. Am I supposed to link it to some other PHP validation script or can it all be in one place?

Here is a link to the test space: www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contactos.php

Here is the PHP: (my syntax is probably off) - Its a combination of Validation and AJAX stuff - file is called: post.php

```
<?php

$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
```

}

```
sleep(3);


if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
}
else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . '.';
}

echo json_encode($return);


?>
```

Here is the JS file (Called: ajaxSubmit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#contactform').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            email : $('#email').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#contactform').show(500);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#contactform').show(500);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

and here is the HTML DOC:

```
<?php
/**
 * @author Brett Vorster <www.kreatif.co.za>
 */
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Orchard Systems 2012 Symposium Register Here" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Orchard Systems, Fruit Growers" />
<title>Orchard Systems 2012 | Contact Form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/style.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styleie7.css" />
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.validate.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#contactform').validate({

showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
   //restore the normal look
   $('#contactform div.xrequired').removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
   //stop if everything is ok
   if (errorList.length == 0) return;
   //Iterate over the errors
   for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
   $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');
},

submitHandler: function(form) {             
    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append("<div id='sadhu'>This is just plain text. I need me a variable of somethink</div>");
    $('#contactform').hide();
    var usr = document.getElementById('contactname').value;
    var eml = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var msg = document.getElementById('message').value;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = usr + " " + eml + msg;
    document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
    form.submit();
}

});
});
</script> 



<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="contact">

<div id="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <img src="images/orchardsystems2012.png" title="Orchard Systems 2012 Logo" />
        <div class="data"><p>
        10th International<br/>Symposium on<br/>Orchard Systems</p></div>
        <div class="location"><p>
        Stellenbosch<br/>South Africa<br/><span>3 - 6 December</span><br/>2012</p>
        </div><a><img class="button" src="images/button_interested.png" title="I am interested - keep me informed" /></a>
    <a href="registration.html" title="Click here to register"><img class="button" src="images/button_attend.png" title="I want to attend - registration form" /></a>
    <a href="abstract.html" title="Click here to submit an abstract" ><img class="button" src="images/button_abstract.png" title="I want to take part - submit an abstract" /></a>
        <img src="images/ishslogo.gif" style="margin:45px 63px 0px 63px;" />
    </div>

    <div id="intainer">

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" tabindex="i" title="Orchard Systems 2012 | Home" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html" tabindex="au" title="About Us" >About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="programme.html" tabindex="p" title="Programme" >Programme</a></li>
                <li><a href="registration.html" tabindex="r" title="Registration Form" >Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="venue.html" tabindex="v" title="Venue" >Venue</a></li>
                <li><a href="accommodation.html" tabindex="a" title="Accommodation" >Accommodation</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours.html" tabindex="t" title="Tours">Tours</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="contact.html" tabindex="c" title="Contact Form">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="header">
        <h3 class="pagetitle">Contact</h3>       
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        <p class="general_site">If you want to be kept in the loop please send us your details and we will update you. Suggestions for workshops are welcome.</p> 

 <div id="message" style="display: none;">
            </div>
            <div id="waiting" style="display: none;">
                Please wait<br />
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" title="Loader" alt="Loader" />
            </div>
            <form action="" id="contactform" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Demo form</legend>
                        <div class="_required"><label for="name">Name*</label><input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" /></div><br/><br/>
                        <div class="_required"><label for="email">E-mail address*</label><input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" /></div><br/><br/>
                        <label for="message">Message</label><textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea><br/>
                        <div class="checko"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="ISHS Member"/><label class="right" for="message">I am interested in a pre-symposium tour</label></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>

        <p class="general_site">Or you can contact Retha Venter on +27 82 6567088 or reventer@netactive.co.za</p>               
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer_content">
        <div class="copyright"><a href="http://www.kreatif.co.za" target="_blank" title="website designed and developed by Kreatif Code.Design">© Orchard Systems 2012<br/>
Designed by kreatif.co.za</a></div>
    <span class="contactno">Tel +27 21 000 0000</span>
    <span class="emailus"><a href="mailto:info@orchardsystems2012.co.za?subject=Email enquiry from the website" title="Click here to email us">info@orchardsystems2012.co.za</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxSubmit.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I've spent the whole weekend trying to find a way to do this. Everytime I feel like I get somewhere and it amounts to nothing... I'm no programmer I dont understand how all of this works but I am learning and just really need to know how to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorted by adding this to the PHP file >

```
    //If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
```

and this >

```
$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";
$return['error'] = false;
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$comments = trim($_POST['message']);
```

hey looks like I'm learning how this stuff works!